# Cause of java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException

Tags: java, multithreading

I am study Cyclic barrier.

I am trying to write code sample:

```
public class Main {

    public static final int PARSER_COUNT = 15;
    public static final int PRODUCT_TRESHOLD = 5;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ProductImporter productImporter = new ProductImporter(PRODUCT_TRESHOLD);

        for (int i = 0; i < PARSER_COUNT; i++) {
            new Thread(new ProductParser(productImporter, "Parser" + (i + 1))).start();
        }
    }
}

class ProductImporter {

    private CyclicBarrier barrier;
    private List<String> parsedProducts;

    public ProductImporter(int productTreshold) {
        parsedProducts = new ArrayList<String>();
        barrier = new CyclicBarrier(productTreshold, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("start import " + parsedProducts);
                parsedProducts.clear();
            }
        });
    }

    public void recharge(String name) {
        try {
            parsedProducts.add(name);
            /*System.out.println("Added product to importList#"+parsedProducts.size());*/
            barrier.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

class ProductParser implements Runnable {

    private String name;
    private Random rand;
    private ProductImporter productImporter;
    private int counter = 0;

    public ProductParser(ProductImporter productImporter, String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.productImporter = productImporter;
        this.rand = new Random();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(12));
                System.out.println(name + " parsed product#" + counter);
                productImporter.recharge(name + "#" + (counter++));
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But I get `java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException`

Please help to understand what do I wrong

### P.S.

Sometimes in output I see foollowing rows:

```
start import [Parser7, Parser4, Parser9, Parser10, Parser2, Parser13, Parser6]
```

Expected result - array with 5 elements

### P.P.S.

output sample:

```
start import [Parser13#21, Parser15#28, Parser12#22, Parser6#19, Parser8#27]
Parser9 parsed product#23
Parser1 parsed product#19
Parser15 parsed product#29
Parser14 parsed product#23
Parser11 parsed product#22
start import [Parser9#23, Parser1#19, Parser15#29, Parser14#23, Parser11#22]
Parser12 parsed product#23
Parser8 parsed product#28
Parser4 parsed product#25
Parser13 parsed product#22
Parser5 parsed product#23
start import [Parser12#23, Parser8#28, Parser4#25, Parser13#22, Parser5#23]
Parser7 parsed product#23
Parser3 parsed product#26
Parser6 parsed product#20
Parser14 parsed product#24
Parser10 parsed product#25
start import [Parser7#23, Parser3#26, Parser6#20, Parser14#24, Parser10#25]
Parser2 parsed product#24
Parser4 parsed product#26
Parser8 parsed product#29
Parser1 parsed product#20
Parser5 parsed product#24
Parser13 parsed product#23
start import [Parser2#24, Parser4#26, Parser8#29, Parser1#20, Parser5#24]
Parser5 parsed product#25
Parser9 parsed product#24
Parser11 parsed product#23
Parser7 parsed product#24
start import [Parser5#25, Parser9#24, Parser11#23, Parser7#24]
Parser10 parsed product#26
Parser3 parsed product#27
Parser1 parsed product#21
Parser13 parsed product#24
Parser7 parsed product#25
start import [Parser10#26, Parser3#27, Parser1#21, Parser13#24, Parser7#25]
Parser2 parsed product#25
Parser10 parsed product#27
Parser7 parsed product#26
Parser15 parsed product#30
Parser12 parsed product#24
start import [Parser2#25, Parser10#27, Parser7#26, Parser15#30, Parser12#24]
Parser6 parsed product#21
Parser14 parsed product#25
Parser11 parsed product#24
Parser5 parsed product#26
Parser13 parsed product#25
Parser1 parsed product#22
Parser4 parsed product#27
Parser11 parsed product#25
Parser11 parsed product#26
Exception in thread "Thread-12" java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.dowait(CyclicBarrier.java:207)
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.await(CyclicBarrier.java:362)
    at lection2.task3.ProductImporter.recharge(Main.java:46)
    at lection2.task3.ProductParser.run(Main.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.dowait(CyclicBarrier.java:250)
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.await(CyclicBarrier.java:362)
    at lection2.task3.ProductImporter.recharge(Main.java:46)
    at lection2.task3.ProductParser.run(Main.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.dowait(CyclicBarrier.java:250)
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.await(CyclicBarrier.java:362)
    at lection2.task3.ProductImporter.recharge(Main.java:46)
    at lection2.task3.ProductParser.run(Main.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.dowait(CyclicBarrier.java:207)
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.await(CyclicBarrier.java:362)
    at lection2.task3.ProductImporter.recharge(Main.java:46)
    at lection2.task3.ProductParser.run(Main.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.dowait(CyclicBarrier.java:207)
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.await(CyclicBarrier.java:362)
    at lection2.task3.ProductImporter.recharge(Main.java:46)
    at lection2.task3.ProductParser.run(Main.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.dowait(CyclicBarrier.java:250)
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.await(CyclicBarrier.java:362)
    at lection2.task3.ProductImporter.recharge(Main.java:46)
    at lection2.task3.ProductParser.run(Main.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.dowait(CyclicBarrier.java:250)
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.await(CyclicBarrier.java:362)
    at lection2.task3.ProductImporter.recharge(Main.java:46)
    at lection2.task3.ProductParser.run(Main.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.dowait(CyclicBarrier.java:207)
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.await(CyclicBarrier.java:362)
    at lection2.task3.ProductImporter.recharge(Main.java:46)
    at lection2.task3.ProductParser.run(Main.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

P.P.P.S

If make sleep interval much better - it works good.

Comment: On which line do you get the exception?

Comment: **} catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }**

Comment: That's where you catch it.  Where is it thrown?

Comment: **barrier.await();**

Comment: *BrokenBarrierException - if another thread was interrupted or timed out while the current thread was waiting, or the barrier was reset, or the barrier was broken when await was called, or the barrier action (if present) failed due to an exception*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run action throws `ConcurrentModificationException`

Because `ArrayList` isn't proper container. Guard acces to it with synchronized block or use thread safe container like `Vector`.

PS: You get more then 5 elements in your `ArrayList` because nothing protect it from being changed.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html#CyclicBarrier-int-java.lang.Runnable-) of the `CyclicBarrier` constructor, it says that:

> Creates a new CyclicBarrier that will trip when the given number of parties (threads) are waiting upon it, and which will execute the given barrier action when the barrier is tripped, performed by the last thread entering the barrier.

So it's likely that there is a race condition between your `ProductImporter.recharge` and barrier action, where the former tries to add to your `parsedProducts` array list and the latter tries to clear it. Two simple fixes to try are:

1. Limit your `ProductParser.run()` to loop to just `PRODUCT_TRESHOLD` iterations.
2. Make your `parsedProducts` thread safe by changing it to a [`java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

Finally, just a general comment about your codes: It doesn't feel right to me for a `main()` to create a number of worker threads to share an instance, and have that shared instance imposes a barrier on the threads. I guess I am more used to seeing a barrier and barrier action being introduced and imposed by a parent thread on all its children threads like the example in the Java [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html).